In WPF app form validation errors not showing up in UI
I'm new to WPF and I need to create a small app in .NET8 that generates text files. In UI I want to have two mandatory fields, one of them accepting only numbers greater than 0. I used fluent validation, mvvm approach and used the INotifyDataErrorInfo alongside INotifyPropertyChanged in my view model. I want the validation to occur on button click, losing focus etc. When I debug the solution, I get the validation errors in the dictionary, but they don't show up in UI. I hope some kind soul can give me some directions on what could be wrong.
The model:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Models
{
    public class TargetFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _size;
        private string _fileName;
        public string Size
        {
            get => _size;
            set
            {
                _size = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Size));
            }
        }

        public string FileName
        {
            get => _fileName;
            set
            {
                _fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FileName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

The view model
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Models;
using ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Validation;
using FluentValidation.Results;

namespace ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private TargetFile _targetFile;
        private readonly TargetFileValidator _validator;
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _targetFile = new TargetFile();
            _validator = new TargetFileValidator();
            _targetFile.PropertyChanged += OnTargetFilePropertyChanged;
        }


        public TargetFile TargetFile
        {
            get => _targetFile;
            set
            {
                if (_targetFile != null)
                    _targetFile.PropertyChanged -= OnTargetFilePropertyChanged;

                _targetFile = value;

                if (_targetFile != null)
                    _targetFile.PropertyChanged += OnTargetFilePropertyChanged;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TargetFile));
                Validate();
            }
        }


        public bool HasErrors => _validationErrors.Any();

        public void Validate()
        {
            var validationResult = _validator.Validate(_targetFile);
            _validationErrors.Clear();

            if (!validationResult.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
                {
                    if (!_validationErrors.ContainsKey(error.PropertyName))
                        _validationErrors.Add(error.PropertyName, new List<string>());

                    _validationErrors[error.PropertyName].Add(error.ErrorMessage);

                    ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(error.PropertyName));
                }

            }

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected void OnTargetFilePropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Validate();
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string? propertyName)
        {
            return _validationErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName ?? string.Empty, out var errors) ? errors : null;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>? ErrorsChanged;
    }
}

The view (xaml):
<Window x:Class="ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Views"
        xmlns:contract="clr-namespace:ABCText.Contract;assembly=ABCText.Contract"
        xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Extensions"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.ViewModels" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:MainViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ABC Text File Generator" Height="300" Width="500">


    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <TextBlock Text="ABC Text File Generator" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock Text="Target approx. file size:" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,5,0" MinHeight="50">

                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TargetFile.Size, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Width="200">
                        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="FileSizeTextBox" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding (Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <ComboBox x:Name="fileSizeTypeComboBox" ItemsSource="{ext:EnumBindingSource contract:FileSizeTypeEnum}" SelectedIndex="0" MaxHeight="19" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock Text="Target file name:" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,5,0" MinHeight="50">

                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TargetFile.FileName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Width="200">
                        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="FileNameTextBox"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding (Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    </TextBox>

                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text=".txt" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Button Content="Generate" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="10,5,10,5" 
                    x:Name="GenerateButton" Click="GenerateButton_Click" 
                    Background="LightSeaGreen"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

The view (code behind):
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.ViewModels;
using ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Models;

namespace ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.DataContext is MainViewModel viewModel)
            {
                viewModel.Validate();
            }
        }
    }
}

The validator:
using ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Models;
using FluentValidation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ABCText.FileGeneratorUI.Validation
{
    public class TargetFileValidator : AbstractValidator<TargetFile>
    {
        public TargetFileValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Size)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Field file size is required.")
                .Must(IsIntegerNumberGreaterThanZero).WithMessage("Field must be a number greater than 0.");

            RuleFor(x => x.FileName)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Field file name is required");
        }

        private bool IsIntegerNumberGreaterThanZero(string value) => int.TryParse(value, out var result) && result > 0;

    }
}


You are missing IDataErrorInfo in your Model. I would suggest having a look here https://gist.github.com/GrantByrne/11243164

In this example, fields are placed directly in the viewmodel and the validation is happening in the viewmodel on the viewmodel entity, however in my case, the model is placed within the viewmodel and the validation of the model is done within the viewmodel. The viewmodel contains the errors collection from validating the "embedded" model and viewmodel implements the necessary INotifyDataErrorInfo. Is my approach with placing the model within the viewmodel wrong in the first place? Because if I were to follow this, the model would be looking almost the same as the viewmodel.

there are multiple issues within your code. 1: You are missing IDataErrorInfo as mentioned (INotifyErrorInfo is not the same). 2: You error collection list is not accessable (since its a private dictionary).
